# Is it possible to perform a Legendre transform from a Gibbs energy $G(T,p,N_i)$ expression to a state function of the form $\phi(T,H,N_i)$?

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to know whether it is possible to use Legendre transforms to transform a Gibbs energy $G(T,p,N_i)$ expression to a state function of the form $\phi(T,H,N)$. $T$ is the temperature, $p$ is the pressure, $N_i$ is the number of particles of type $i$, and $H$ is the enthalpy. If so, what is $\phi$?

I am unsure since pressure and enthalpy are not the usual conjugate variables seen in textbook thermodynamics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  One of the main properties of the Legendre transform is that when we apply it to a particular argument, the transformed function is a "natural" function of the derivative of the original function with respect to that argument.  For example, in classical mechanics, the derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to a velocity is the momentum;  and the Legendre transform of the Lagrangian is the Hamiltonian, which is a "natural" function of the momentum, not the velocity.

So if you wanted to apply a Legendre transform to a function $f(T, p, N_i)$ to get a "natural" function of $T$, $H$, and $N_i$, it would need to be the case that
$$
\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial p} \right)_{T, N_i} = H, 
$$
and the Gibbs free energy definitely doesn't satisfy that property.  There's some function $f$ that does (just integrate $H$ with respect to $p$), but it's almost certainly not terribly physically meaningful, and the Gibbs free energy ain't it.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in Seifert's answer, it is impossible to obtain your function $\phi$ by Legendre's transform. Quite in general, not all the state functions can be obtained by Legendre's transform. For instance, we may describe a simple system via the internal energy $U$, as a function of entropy ($S$), volume ($V$), and $N$, but also via the function $S(U,V,N)$. In this case too, $S$ and $U$ are not connected by a Legendre transform.

One could try to find a state function of the form you suggest without Legendre transforms. If the desired state function was a function of the form $\phi(T,G,N)$, this is certainly possible.

It is enough to notice that the relation
$$
G=G(T,p,N),
$$
via the implicit function theorem, defines $p$ as a function of $T$, $G$, and $N$. Indeed, the obvious condition
$$
\left.\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{p}}\right|_{T,N}=V>0
$$
is a sufficient condition for the theorem.

Therefore one can get $p(T,G,N)$ as a function of the state.  In this case, it is more than that. It can be used as a fundamental equation(*) on the same foot as the other thermodynamic potentials or as the entropy and the related Massieu's functions (see Callen's textbook on thermodynamics or [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massieu_function)). It is a simple exercise to show that this fundamental equation is maximum at equilibrium.

The case of $p(T,H,N)$ is not that easy. The problem is that
$$
\left.\frac{\partial{H}}{\partial{p}}\right|_{T,N}=
-T\left.\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{T}}\right|_{p,N}+V.
$$
The first term in the last equality is proportional to the thermal expansion coefficient and it has not a definite sign. Therefore we cannot use the implicit function theorem without additional hypotheses.

With a similar strategy, it would be possible to have a state function (and a fundamental equation) in the form of $p(S,H,N)$.

(*) Fundamental equations (also called characteristic (state) functions) are state functions containing complete information about a thermodynamic system.

Comment: @LodinEllingsen, please, have a look at the corrected version of the answer.

Comment: @LodinEllingsen, no. They are both functions of the state (do not depend on the processes). However, from $p(T,H,N)$ alone, there is some thermodynamic information that cannot be obtained without adding some additional state function. It is analogous to the problem one has if only the perfect gas equation of state is given. There is no way to get the specific heat without additional information.

Comment: @LodinEllingsen, yes, it is not a characteristic state function.However, checking again what I wrote, I realize that I made an initial mistake (basically I was thinking in terms of $G(T,p,N)$ even if I was writing $H$. Therefore also the first part is not correct (the partial derivative at constant $T$ of $H$ is not V. I'll go to modify for the last time my answer.

Comment: @LodinEllingsen, now the answer should be correct. I would cancel all my comments but the first to avoid cluttering the page with the history of the answer. I suggest you do the same if you think it is ok. I'll wait for your decision to avoid making completely ununderstandable the sequence of comments.